# Why are smartgwt elements invisible after deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, smartgwt

I'm trying to deploy the easy project like 
http://uptick.com.au/content/create-gwt-project using the following environment:

- SmartGWT 4.0p
- Eclipse 4.2
- GWT 2.5.1

when it's deployed I don't see SmartGWT visual elements. Could someone explain why please?

Refer http://3-dot-needtools2.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with path to skin files. It seems somewhere you used wrong register: your app tries to load it by address http://3-dot-needtools2.appspot.com/Test/sc/skins/Enterprise/skin_styles.css but really they are in http://3-dot-needtools2.appspot.com/test/sc/skins/Enterprise/skin_styles.css - see that Test folder should starts with t, not T. 
I recommend you to check where you write Test and replace it to test. Also check your Test.gwt.xml file - it should have line

```
<module rename-to='test'>
```

Btw, it works fine for you locally because you use windows and it's file system is register independent.